# Align text by its median

Tags: html, css, centering

In typography text has a `mean-line`, or `midline` which is halfway between the `baseline` and the `cap height`.
The Wikipedia uses this image for reference:
[image]

Is it possible to align text by its median line in css?
The following example displays a centered text above a red line.

```css
#box {
    background: lightblue;
    width: min-content;
    height:  3em;
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
    font-size: 50px;
    
    /* Needed for red center line */
    position: relative;
}

/* Red center line */
#cline {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <div id="cline"></div>
    Sphinx
</div>
```

*The baseline in the image is only red by coincidence.

The Wikipedia didn't have a svg with a red median line.*

Comment: do you mean use this : vertical-align: baseline;

Comment: @sajadsalimzadeh Aligning the text by it's baseline pushes it even further up. Aligning by the median line would push the text in the example a little bit further down, so that the red line would be just above the `p`

Comment: No...there is no such setting/property.

Answer (score 0):

No, but css has `vertical-align` property, with an appropriate font, line-height, font-size, screen, we can archive this goal...

```css
  p {
    background: brown;
    font-size:30px;
  }
  span {
    font-size: 60px;
    color:darkgoldenrod;
  }
  .top {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .baseline {
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
```

```html
  <p>Default text <span class="top"> top align text</span></p>
  <p>Default text <span class="baseline"> baseline align text</span></p>
```

`vertical-align` only works on **inline element**, the result is depend on the height of the `line-box`, which is determined by `line-height`, `font` and `font-size`, that is why sometimes even we set `vertical-align: middle;`, the text is not middle aligned.

Comment: the question asks allignment wrt. median/midline notbase nor top